# Does Gitlab-CI support variable expansion within only:refs?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've got a large .gitlab-ci.yml file with lots of jobs in it.  Many of these jobs are filtered to only run on certain branches.  When managing this file it would be convenient to define the names of these branches as variables at the top of the file so that only the variables need to be updated if the branch names change.  This is a pretty standard practice for constants in most programming languages.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this works in Gitlab-CI:

```
variables:
  THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK: "this_works"

lots:
  only:
    refs:
      - this_works
  script:
    - echo "lots"

of:
  only:
    refs:
      - $THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK
  script:
    - echo "of"

jobs:
  only:
    refs:
      - $THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK
  script:
    - echo "jobs"
```

In the above example, only the "lots" job will be run since the THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK variable is not expanded in the "of" and "jobs" jobs.

The [closest documentation which I can find](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) doesn't mention anything about the only:refs keyword.  It does go into details on the only:variables keyword.  This keyword could provide a nice workaround if we could do something like this instead:

```
variables:
  THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK: "this_works"

lots:
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "this_works"
  script:
    - echo "lots"

of:
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK
  script:
    - echo "of"

jobs:
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $THIS_DOES_NOT_WORK
  script:
    - echo "jobs"
```

In this case it's explicitly stated in the documentation that this won't work. 
 The only:variables keyword used for filtering on variable comparisons is ironically incapable of expanding variables.

Is there some other workaround here?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html, it seems that the capability of the ci pipeline increased and it can actually expand variables, now. For me the solution was to use parts of your example:

```
jobs:
  only:
    variables:
      - $THIS_DOES_WORK == $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  script:
    - echo "jobs"
```

In my case $THIS_DOES_WORK is a variable passed from the gitlab ui via the CI/CD variables tab. Gitlab states the constraints variables used in this scope have:

The variable must be in the form of $variable. Not supported are the following:

- Variables that are based on the environment’s name (CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME, CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG).
- Any other variables related to environment (currently only CI_ENVIRONMENT_URL).
- [Persisted variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#persisted-variables).

Additionally, you should pay attention that the variable is not set to protected, if working on an unprotected branch.